# OpenLayer - Show data on Popup using Flask

Tags: postgresql, flask, openlayers

I have made a OpenLayer map which gets data from a SQL database using Flask. It shows a marker and a popup according to data stored in the database. 
I would like to somehow show data in the popup that is retrieved through Flask, at the moment i can only show a string "Name". Is there a method to show the data from `mydata.gps_longitude` inside the popup?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="mapdiv"></div>
        <script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
        <script>
            map = new OpenLayers.Map("mapdiv");
            map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());

            var aarhusLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat( 10.102390 ,56.128181 )
                .transform(
                    new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
                    map.getProjectionObject() // to Spherical Mercator Projection
                );
            var zoom=11;

            var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
            map.addLayer(markers);
            map.setCenter (aarhusLat, zoom);



            var locationData = {
                gps_latitude : [{% for mydata in myIotdata %}
                    {{ mydata.gps_latitude }},
                {% endfor %}],
                gps_longitude : [{% for mydata in myIotdata %}
                    {{ mydata.gps_longitude }},
                {% endfor %}]
            }

            /* console.log(locationData.gps_latitude[0]); */

            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < locationData.gps_latitude.length; i++) {

                var aarhusLat2 = new OpenLayers.LonLat( locationData.gps_longitude[i], locationData.gps_latitude[i] )
                    .transform(
                    new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
                    map.getProjectionObject() // to Spherical Mercator Projection
                );
            markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(aarhusLat2));
                        var student = new OpenLayers.Layer.Text('GPS')

                        // A popup with some information about our location
                        var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
                        "Popup",
                        aarhusLat2,
                        // I added a size to make it fit in the small fiddle window
                        new OpenLayers.Size(100,100),
                                "Name", // Here i would like to display the data from locationdata.
                        null,
                        true // set to true to enable a (x) button. false othervise
                    );
                    map.addPopup(popup); //Draw popup window on map.
                        map.addLayer(student);
                    }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: It's looks like this at the moment]